# "Brendon's url" and Chinese apps on home screen. Is it a virus? How do I fix it?

Tags: notifications, home-screen-shortcuts, malware

My tab was charging when I noticed there were notifications in Chinese and unknown home screen shortcuts created. Some were named "Brendon's URL" and the others were in Chinese. The notifications were also in Chinese. Is there anything wrong? Is it a virus? How do I fix it?

[image: pic 1] [image: pic 3] [image: pic 2]

<sub>Image taken from [an XDA forum thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/weird-icons-android-phone-t2894419/), click to view the larger version.</sub>

Comment: If you long press the notification and press "App Info" what does it bring up?

Comment: Related: [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/general/general/weird-icons-android-phone-t2894419/), [Blogspot](http://androidhubportal.blogspot.sg/2014/10/brendons-url-new-android-virus.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is downloaded by "Software Update" App Version 09.05.
Force stop it and disable for time being.

Comment: Thanks.how can i re-enable "Software Update" app?

Comment: setting-> Device-> Apps -> disabled -> software update -> enable.
But i will recommend to keep it disable until Antivirus come up with its solution.

Comment: There's no option for disable..only option is force stop. So if i force it to stop, then how can i regain it back? My software update version is 08.07

Comment: After Force stop it will show launch option, You can launch it any time afterwords. Even after force stop when you will restart your phone it will restart again.

Comment: No launch button showing but problem solved. Thank you very much bro. Hope so it again come to play on reboot.

Comment: Nitin, What do u think is it a virus or an error in the software because i hadn't updated it. I don't know from where it came from?

Answer (score 0):

try this: cut off any connection by activating Airplane mode. if you have wechat installed on your android then uninstall it first. after that remove all the brandon's url u have. restart your phone and wait...see it if IT appear again. IF not appear then restore your connection/OFF your airplane mode.

Comment: i did as richard said . airplane mode on delete shortcuts. reboot handset. switch off airplane mode. now everything is a ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to freeze the ota updater apps using TB or any third party app that can freeze apps. This works on my co-group member in our facebook group.